# Excel VBA Using wildcard to replace string within string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a difficult situation and so far no luck in finding a solution.

My VBA collects number figures like `$80,000.50.` and I'm trying to get VBA to remove the last period to make it look like `$80,000.50` but without using right().

The problem is after the last period there are hidden spaces or characters which will be a whole lot of new issue to handle so I'm just looking for something like:

`replace("$80,000.50.",".**.",".**")`

Is this possible in VBA?

Comment: `TRIM()` will get rid of leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: If there are no periods among the characters at the end you could do this with a formula (and convert into VBA).

Comment: Unclear-------------if the string contains **A.B...C..X.YZ** do you want **A.B...C..X** or **A.B...C..XYZ**

Comment: Thanks guys, I already tried TRIM but because the string came from HTML body there are the usual hidden spaces that trim and clear couldn't find.

Comment: See my answer below for a one liner which deals with all junk characters at the end, with no need for `Trim`! Actually learned something myself writing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant leave a comment so....

what about InStrRev?

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim this As String
    this = "$80,000.50."
    this = Left(this, InStrRev(this, ".") - 1)
    Debug.Print ; this
End Sub
```

Comment: why not show an example of this using the data from above and Right, then this would be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @ScottCraner UGH fine :P <3

Comment: Sorry actually you would use Left not Right.

Comment: This could work. There are 2 periods in the figure and I only wanted to make sure the last one is omitted or excluded. I can perhaps use InStrRev but with a +3 instead of a -1

Comment: @jay why would you use +3? the "-1" removes the period...+3 would go in the opposite direction?

Comment: @Phesago oh sorry I got confused, I thought InStrRev reads the other period first

Comment: Thanks man, this works and it's definitely a one-liner, so simple and easy `this = Left(this, InStrRev(this, ".") - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

### Mid + Find

You can use Mid and Find functions. Like so:

[image]

The `Find` will find the first dot `.` character. If all the values you are collecting are currency with 2 decimals, stored as text, this will work well.

The formula is: `=MID(A2,1,FIND(".",A2)+2)`

### VBA solution

```
Function getStringToFirstOccurence(inputUser As String, FindWhat As String) As String
    getStringToFirstOccurence = Mid(inputUser, 1, WorksheetFunction.Find(FindWhat, inputUser) + 2)
End Function
```

### Other possible solutions, hints

Trim + Clear + Substitute(Char(160)): [Chandoo -
Untrimmable Spaces – Excel Formula](http://chandoo.org/wp/2017/01/12/untrimmable-spaces-excel-formula/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+PointyHairedDilbert+%28Chandoo.org+-+Learn+Excel+%26+Charting+Online%29)
Ultimately, you can implement Regular expressions into Excel UDF: [VBScript’s Regular Expression Support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

Comment: Sorry, it has to be VBA :s

Comment: @jay see vba solution. its basicaly a copy, just different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Text
        l = Len(s)
        For i = l To 1 Step -1
            If Mid(s, i, 1) = "." Then
                r.Value = Mid(s, 1, i - 1) & Mid(s, i + 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next r
End Sub
```

This will remove the last period and leave all the other characters intact.  Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**EDIT#1**:

This version does not require looping over the characters in the cell:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        If InStr(r.Value, ".") > 0 Then r.Characters(InStrRev(r.Text, "."), 1).Delete
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a longer approach. I have a feeling a shorter approach is out there without having to loop through each characters

Comment: @jay  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

**Shortest Solution**

Simply use the `Val` command. I assume this is meant to be a numerical figure anyway? Get rid of commas and the dollar sign, then convert to value, which will ignore the second point and any other trailing characters! Robustness not tested, but seems to work...

```
Dim myString as String
myString = "$80,000.50.   junk characters     "

' Remove commas and dollar signs, then convert to value.
Dim myVal as Double
myVal = Val(Replace(Replace(myString,"$",""),",",""))

' >> myVal = 80000.5

' If you're really set on getting a formatted string back, use Format:
myString = Format(myVal, "$000,000.00")

' >> myString = $80,000.50
```

From the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx),

> The Val function stops reading the string at the first character it can't recognize as part of a number. Symbols and characters that are often considered parts of numeric values, such as dollar signs and commas, are not recognized.

This is why we must first remove the dollar sign, and why it ignores all the junk after the second dot, or for that matter anything non numerical at the end!

**Working with Strings**

Edit: I wrote this solution first but now think the above method is more comprehensive and shorter - left here for completeness.

`Trim()` removes whitespace at the end of a string. Then you could simply use `Left()` to get rid of the last point...

```
' String with trailing spaces and a final dot
Dim myString as String
myString = "$80,000.50.    "

' Get rid of whitespace at end
myString = Trim(myString)

' Might as well check if there is a final dot before removing it
If Right(myString, 1) = "." Then

    myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)

End If

' >> myString = "$80,000.50"
```